How can I upload the files with the camera in my app with 12 release of Customwebview Extension of App Inventor?
Webviewextra blocks
Which blocks should I use in app inventor with
Customwebview extension to open camera in my app when I add the files?
Could anyone show me how this example may be adjusted?
When I choose file in my app, it does not show me the camera option.
I want to know also how reload pages and how come back pages which blocks I have to use. The photo is about webviewextra extension but I want the example with customwebview 12 release extension

The extension you are using does not configure the webviewer to connect to or ask permission for the device camera. Find another extension that can do this (customwebview), or take pictures, then select them from the webviewer.

Can you show me the blocks of Customwebview 12 extension that do the app to select files with the camera option, reload the pages and come back the pages?

Look on the AI2 community in the Customwebview topic.
